# c++ return type of function to be a function of it's input

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning c++ I am wondering if there is a way to define a template where the return type would actually be a function of the input of the function.

For example:

```
calling fun(1) would return me an int
calling fun(2) would return me a float
```

I guess this could be done using some kind of map?

```
1 <> int
2 <> float
```

The problem I was trying to solve is, for example, if I have an object called room I wanted to have a function called get_contents on which I would pass an enum to define the return type. For example:

```
std::vector<Table> tables = room.get_contents(Room::TABLE);
std::vector<Chair> chairs = room.get_contents(Room::CHAIR);
```

The first question probably isn't the best solution to this problem, nevertheless I wanted to know if it possible. Also, what is the best pattern to do what I want?

Comment: Try creating a base class, such as `class Furnature`, and have the function return a pointer to the base class.

Comment: `template<class FurnitureType> FurnitureType get_contents()`

Comment: You can return a vector of parent objects (e.g. of a Furniture class from which the Table and Chair classes extend), and cast the results manually. I would personally decide against this, as would many people who are reading this, banging their heads on their desks for even mentioning it. Please, please do not do this. A templating approach makes more sense. Separated methods make even more sense - I would have to question the structural integrity of a program that requires this (it's something you may see a lot in dynamically-typed languages - C++ is a different animal entirely)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to me like `room.get` just needs to be a template, and forget the enum.

```
std::vector<Table> tables = room.get<Table>();`
```

Answer (score 0):

The language doesn't allow you to do that.

Think about it, the input for your function could be a variable, whose value is not known at compile time. The compiler won't be able to deduce the return type.

What you can do:

- Use two different functions and call the appropriate one.
- Have a common return type, e.g. a base class pointer or reference.

Comment: I would more correctly state that allowing it requires solving the Halting Problem so can never be allowed by any statically-typed language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use templating for a function, but you will have to explicitly pass the type as the template parameter, it always has to be known at compile-time can't be inferred from the input automatically:

```
template <typename T>
T product(T x, T y) { x * y; }
```

and call it as:

```
product<int>(3,2);
```

(abstract example, may be less useful in what you are doing)